# #1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql

I am gettings this error when I try query bellow
SELECT pib FROM firme_virmani WHERE id IN ( SELECT id_firme FROM `narudzbine_virmani` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY pib DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

join a subquery instead of using the IN operator:

```
select pib
from firme_virmani
join (
    SELECT id_firme FROM narudzbine_virmani ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
) ids on firme_virmani.id=ids.id_firme
order by pib desc
limit 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=74d4361857768c43485b7faffe4e4507)